# Return results from executor in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I need some help retrieving results from executors. The place where I create the workers:

```
public static void method()
    {
        double bestProb = 0;
        double best p1 = 10000;
        double best p2 = 10000;

        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        List<Future<Double>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            double p1 = Math.pow(2, i);
            for (int j = 5; j < 15; j++) {
                double p2 = Math.pow(2, j);
                Callable<Double> worker = new ProbabilityCalculator(p1, p2,);
                futures.add(executor.submit(worker));
                }
            }

        for (Future<Double> future : futures) {
             double prob = future.get();
             prob /= 100;   

                if (prob > bestProb) {
                    bestProb = prob;
                    bestp1 = p1;
                    bestp2 = p2;
                }
}

        System.out.println("Best prob: " + bestProb + ", for: " + bestp1 + ", " + bestp2);
    }
```

The `ProbabilityCalculator` class which I want to return a probability that I have to process back in the `method` with the parameters `p1` and `p2` that lead to this probability.

```
public class ProbabilityCalculator implements Callable<Double> {
    private double p1;
    private double p2;
    private double probability;

    private void processCommand() {
     // perform operations
     // here I compute the probability each time
    }          
    public double returnProbability() {
         return this.probability;
    }

    @Override
    public void call() {
        processCommand();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Well you're using `Runnable` to start with, which doesn't return a result. You should start with `Callable<V>` which *does* return a result. It's not clear what `WorkerThread` is either, but if it actually extends `Thread`, it's odd to submit that to an executor...

Comment: `WorkerThread` performs operations on a set of data. And after these operations are done I want a result to be returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answer was provided when the question was at revision 1. The OP is editing the question in response to the answer, which makes the answer make less sense - rather than me try to keep up with the edits, please refer to revision 1 to see what this was all responding to...)

If you use `Callable` instead of `Runnable`, you can use the future returned by the executor to get the return value. If you *just* want the probabilities, you could use a `Callable<Double>` like this:

```
List<Future<Double>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    double p1 = Math.pow(2, i);
    for (int j = 5; j < 15; j++) {
        double p2 = Math.pow(2, j);
        Callable<Double> worker = new ProbabilityCalculator(p1, p2);
        futures.add(executor.submit(worker));           
    }
}
// Do whatever else you want to here...

// Now wait for the results and handle them appropriately.
// Note the exceptions that can be thrown...
for (Future<Double> future : futures) {
    double value = future.get();
    ...
}
```

The important thing here is that a `Runnable` doesn't return a value, whereas a `Callable` does.

As it sounds like you need the `p1` and `p2` values as well, you should probably encapsulate that in a result type, so you'd implement `Callable<ProbabilityResult>`, e.g.

```
public class ProbabilityCalculator implements Callable<ProbabilityResult> {
    private final double p1, p2;

    public ProbabilityCalculator(double p1, double p2) {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }

    public ProbabilityResult call() {
        double probabilty = ...;
        return new ProbabilityResult(p1, p2, probability);
    }
}
```

(Where `ProbabilityResult` would just be a simple data transfer class, effectively - you *could* just use a `double[]` with three values, but that would be fairly unpleasant...)

Now you can use:

```
double bestProbability = -1;
double bestP1 = 0, bestP2 = 0;
for (Future<ProbabilityResult> future : futures) {
    ProbabilityResult result = future.get();
    if (result.getProbability() > bestProbability) {
        bestProbability = result.getProbability();
        bestP1 = result.getP1();
        bestP2 = result.getP2();
    }
}
```

Note that I've changed `WorkerThread` to `ProbabilityCalculator` - you should *not* be creating an instance of a subclass of `Thread` here; the point is for the executor to handle the actual threading; you just provide it the tasks to execute. If your `WorkerThread` class doesn't actually extend `Thread`, you should rename it to something less misleading.

Comment: Can you check the updated question please? I tried to use some of the code you provided.

Comment: @GeR: Editing a question so that my answer looks nonsensical is bad form. Additionally, you haven't said what went wrong with the updated code - I suspect it fails to compile because you're not returning anything from `call`, and because you're implementing the raw type instead of `Callable<Double>`. I suggest you roll the question back to the version which my answer actually addresses, and try to implement `Callable<Double>` properly...

Comment: I didn't edit the question so that your answer will be nonsensical. I have implemented what you said and also added the `ProcessCalculator` in order to have more code so you can figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @GeR: Yes you did. My answer says that you should be using `Callable`, not `Runnable` - but the question doesn't *use* `Runnable`, so the answer doesn't make sense. Likewise my references to `WorkerThread`, which you've now removed.

Comment: @GeR: I've edited my answer to take account of you needing the `p1` and `p2` values as well.

Comment: Ok so then I should open another question? I have edited the question because I encounter new problems. I work on a project than runs for hours, so I believed that threads could help me minimize the execution time. So this is the first time I use them, I have no experience with them. That's why I came here for some help..

Comment: @GeR: Yes, you should ask *one* question per post. Stack Overflow isn't some sort of interactive debugging tool. I explained how to use the result of a task submitted to an executor - if you have problems understanding that answer, you should ask for more details in comments. If you then run into later problems, put that in a different question.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that. Right now I try to implement the solution you provided.